# Send invite to "like" restaurant where emails are collected

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, newsletter

I'd like to collect emails from customers at my restaurant on a piece of paper at the door and then send them an invite to 'like' us on facebook - does anyone know if this is possible to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed the code generated by this page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

in your email. It should show how many people like the page, as well as a link to click on. It does require that your users are viewing the email as HTML and that they allow images for everything to display properly.

Alternately, you could simply send them a link to the page itself and ask them to Like it once they get there.

Comment: this actually doesn't work because most emails don't accept iframes or javascript. The way I'm going to do this is redirect to a web page.